# Laravel - Bootstrap Javascript's conflict with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

Has anyone experienced this?

Bootstrap's `Javascript` (For `modals`, `accordion`, and other animations) has conflict for my `Chart.js`.

Here's the [cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Chart.js) link, I used the minified version. (Chart.min.js)

If this helps, I'll show my `script` for the chart:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        responsive: true,
        type:'line',
        data:{
            labels:['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
            datasets:[{
                label:'Sales',
                data:[
                    500,
                    304,
                    601,
                    670,
                    912,
                    612,
                    500
                ],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(129, 207, 238, 1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#000',
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: '#000'
            }]
        },
        options:{
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                    }
                }]
            },

            title:{
                display: true,
                text: 'Weekly Sales',
                fontSize: 25
            },

            legend:{
                position:'bottom',
                display:false,
            },

            layout:{
                padding: 50,
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

It's a `line chart` that has a default value (for testing).
The chart disappears after a split second, and because of this. I knew that it was because of the Bootstrap's `javascript`.

Whenever I take off, or `comment` out the `script` tag for the Bootstrap's `javascript`, the chart shows with no problem at all. But my `modal` and other `animations` doesn't work now.

I somehow want both of them to work, because I need them both.

Answer (score 2):

This may be the most frustrating (bug/feature/problem) I have ever come accross and got me stuck for a few days, but because my boss doesn't take no for an answer and I hate giving up, I finally managed to solve it. The answer thought me something about html and javascript I never knew:

### The answer:

In the `<head></head>` of your html file you need to change the way bootstrap call's it's `app.js` from this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Note the missing `defer` tag.

### The explanation:

You may be wondering, what does the `defer` tag do? And to answer that I give you this small snippet:

```html
<html>

<body>

  <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_defer.js" defer></script>

  <p id="p1">
    Hello World!
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

It simply stops the browser from loading/running the script until the site has been completely parsed. In the above example the script we call contains the following code:

```
alert(document.getElementById("p1").firstChild.nodeValue);
```

Basically telling your browser to send an alert with the contents of whatever is inside the p tags. Without the `defer` tag, the script would fail because it would be run before the p tags get parsed by the browser, and javascript can only work with what the browser already parsed.

As far as I found, removing the defer tag doesn't break anything in bootstrap, so I don't know why it even has a defer tag.

I'm also not quite sure why this would be a problem for chart.js, If anyone knows I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after removing the `defer` attribute that @TDM talked about. I solved this simply by adding an *DOMContentLoaded* event listener.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    new Chart(ctx, {...});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

had this same problem however removing defer attribute made other elements not to work in my laravel application. So I allowed defer on the app.js script and used the bellow suggested by @jakub to get it loaded after the dom element.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", 
    function () {
        new Chart(...);
    }
);
```